# Using sed to ignore the start of a file and match on regex somewhere else within the string

Tags: bash, sed

So I am attempting to solve a parsing issue I am faced with...

I have a log file which contains pseudorandom strings at the start of each line.  They can be anything but will always be the same length, which is the first data set I wish to keep (E.G `start-of-log-001 -` ) made up of 19 characters, including the space.

```
start-of-log-001 - bacon bacon email1@email.com bacon metadata123 bacon 123 bacon
start-of-log-002 - bacon bacon metadata123 bacon email2@email.com bacon 123 bacon
start-of-log-010 - bacon bacon metadata123 bacon bacon bacon 123 bacon email3@email.com
```

The second part of the data set I want to extract is the email addresses, but that is proving a little more tricky because they can be anywhere within the rest of the string.  My aim is to keep each lines 'start-of-file' value and its associated email on the same line as they relate to each other, but to remove anything else.  I am currently using the following Regex (I understand there is a small possibility it won't catch every email).

```
[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]
```

So that regex should pull out the emails but I need a way to run through each of these lines, parse them to keep the first 19 characters, and then remove all data apart from the email for that line, so it will result in the following.

```
start-of-log-001 - email1@email.com
start-of-log-002 - email2@email.com
start-of-log-010 - email3@email.com
```

I have looked into regex positive lookbehinds and sed strings but cannot get anything to work thus far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does any other word contain `@`, or is the email address always `@` surrounded by non-blank characters?

Comment: The only '@' character in each string will be for the email address on that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification of what a makes up a valid email address is quite complex (see [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6)), so instead of trying to do that, we can just say "the email address is the longest match of non-blanks around the `@` sign".

This command extracts the first 19 characters and then the aforementioned longest match of non-blanks:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(.{19}).*[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]*@[^[:blank:]]*).*/\1\2/' infile
start-of-log-001 - email1@email.com
start-of-log-002 - email2@email.com
start-of-log-010 - email3@email.com
```

- `-E` (extended regular expressions) is just for convenience; without it, we have to escape `()` and `{}` to `\(\)` and `\{\}`.
- `^(.{19})` matches and captures the first 19 characters per line.
- `[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]*@[^[:blank:]]*)` is a blank, then the `@` sign surrounded by non-blanks. The first blank is required because the greedy matching would otherwise match `.*` up to the `@` sign.

The substitution then just places the two captured groups next to each other.

---

Side note: within bracket expressions, nothing has to be escaped, so yours could just be `[[:alnum:]+._-]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/^(.{19}).*? ([^@]+@[^ ]*).*/\1\2/'
```

Comment: Small nit: `.*?` doesn't do non-greedy matching in sed. I'm actually surprised that it doesn't break the regex (thought it'd expect a literal `?`), but it works fine.